# two Lists to Json Format in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two lists

```
a=["USA","France","Italy"]
b=["10","5","6"]
```

I want the end result to be in json like this.

```
[{"country":"USA","wins":"10"},
{"country":"France","wins":"5"},
{"country":"Italy","wins":"6"},
]
```

I used zip(a,b) to join two but couldn't name it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Using [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
>>> [{'country': country, 'wins': wins} for country, wins in zip(a, b)]
[{'country': 'USA', 'wins': '10'},
 {'country': 'France', 'wins': '5'},
 {'country': 'Italy', 'wins': '6'}]
```

Use [`json.dumps`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.dumps) to get JSON:

```
>>> json.dumps(
...     [{'country': country, 'wins': wins} for country, wins in zip(a, b)]
... )
'[{"country": "USA", "wins": "10"}, {"country": "France", "wins": "5"}, {"country": "Italy", "wins": "6"}]'
```

Comment: Can someone explain the python syntactic magic of [{'country': country, 'wins': wins} for country, wins in zip(a, b)]? I just tried the line in the interpreter and it works! But I can't find good documentation on this. Anyone can point me in the right direction. I am very interested in it.

Comment: @KyleCalica-St, Follow the link in the answer. It will lead you to the Python tutorial explaning about the list comprehension.

Answer (score 4):

You first have to set it up as a list, and then add the items to it

```
import json

jsonList = []
a=["USA","France","Italy"]
b=["10","5","6"]

for i in range(0,len(a)):
    jsonList.append({"country" : a[i], "wins" : b[i]})


print(json.dumps(jsonList, indent = 1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can combine `map` with `zip`.

```
jsonized = map(lambda item: {'country':item[0], 'wins':item[1]}, zip(a,b))
```

Comment: [Tuple parameter unpacking does not work in Python 3.x.](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3113/)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer of 'falsetru' if you need an actual json object (and not only a string with the structure of a json) you can use `json.loads()` and use as parameter the string that `json.dumps()` outputs.

Answer (score 0):

also for just combine two list to json format:

```
def make_json_from_two_list():
    keys = ["USA","France","Italy"]
    value = ["10","5","6"]
    jsons = {}
    x = 0
    for item in keys:
        jsons[item[0]] = value[x]
        x += 1
    return jsons

print(ake_json_from_two_list())
```

result>>>> {"USA":"10","France":"5","Italy":"6"}